# Any disadvantages of wrapping the constructor and prototype methods in an IIFE?

Tags: javascript

Is there any disadvantages of using this pattern?

```
var Animal = (function() {
  function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  Animal.prototype.move = function(meters) {
    return alert(this.name + (" moved " + meters + "m."));
  };

  return Animal;

})();
```

I think it's nice for readability to encapsulate everything in an Immediately Invoked Function Expression and I know this is what CoffeeScript's classes compile to.

Comment: In your particular example, nothing is gained, as the private scope created with IIFE is never utilized.

Comment: This is good approach. Pretty flexible, allows private functions and prototypes. Plus you don't scatter implementation all over the file, everything is inside an IIEF.

Comment: The only disadvantage could be if you have very large variables in the IIFE it'll not go out of scope unless you delete them or set them to something less consuming like undefined. For lazy loaded functionality you can always add to the prototype later but these methods won't be able to access shared privates.

Answer (score 1):

It is not so compact, I usually use shortcuts like these:

```
var Animal = Object.extend({
    initialize: function (name) {
        this.name = name;
    },
    move: function(meters) {
        return alert(this.name + (" moved " + meters + "m."));
    }
});
```

or

```
var Animal = Class({
    initialize: function (name) {
        this.name = name;
    },
    move: function(meters) {
        return alert(this.name + (" moved " + meters + "m."));
    }
});
```

Otherwise there is no problem with your approach, so ofc, you can use it...

There is an advantage by data hiding, you can use static private variables (if we'd talk about classes) by putting your constructors into closures. We usually use this approach at module level for data hiding, by constructors it simply does not worth the effort...